# Finding a row in a table and inserting values from userform

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry i have edited this so many times its confusing so i will just start fresh. i wrote 2 different functions both are working and ive tried to combine the 2 to get this functional but im having trouble. i want to find a row with a match name then insert values in 5 columns for that row.

Right now i am getting an error "object doesnt support this property or method" at this line:

.Cells(LastRow, 5).Value = TextBox1.Value

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()
    If ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Select a member of staff", , "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If CheckBox1.Value = False And CheckBox2.Value = False And CheckBox3.Value = False And CheckBox4.Value = False And CheckBox5.Value = False Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        Dim Counter As Integer, EmployeeName As String, LastRow As Long
        Call SmoothCodeStart
        EmployeeName = ComboBox1.Value
        With Sheets("Timetable").ListObjects("TblTimetable")
        LastRow = .range.Rows.Count
            For Counter = LastRow To 1 Step -1
            If .DataBodyRange.Cells(Counter, .ListColumns("Name and Surname").Index) = EmployeeName Then
                .Cells(LastRow, 4).Value = TextBox1.Value
                .Cells(LastRow, 5).Value = TextBox2.Value
                .Cells(LastRow, 6).Value = TextBox3.Value
                .Cells(LastRow, 7).Value = TextBox4.Value
                .Cells(LastRow, 8).Value = TextBox5.Value
            End If
            Next Counter
        End With
    End If
    Call SmoothCodeEnd
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Right i have started from the beginning, this code finds the correct row and deletes it, now istead of deleting it i want it to add the values from textboxes 1:5 to columns 4:8

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()
    If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Select a member of staff", , "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If CheckBox1.Value = False And CheckBox2.Value = False And CheckBox3.Value = False And CheckBox4.Value = False And CheckBox5.Value = False Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        Dim Counter As Integer, EmployeeName As String, LastRow As Long

        EmployeeName = ComboBox1.Value
        With Sheets("Timetable").ListObjects("TblTimetable")
            LastRow = .range.Rows.Count
            For Counter = LastRow To 1 Step -1
            If .DataBodyRange.Cells(Counter, .ListColumns("Name and Surname").Index) = EmployeeName Then
                .ListRows(Counter).Delete
            End If
            Next Counter
        End With
    End If
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

I have tried instead of:

```
.Cells(LastRow, 4).Value = TextBox1.Value
```

using this instead:

```
 .Cells(Counter, 4).Value = TextBox1.Value
```

and ive tried this:

```
With .ListRows(Counter)
   .Columns(, 4).Value = TextBox1.Value
End With
```

New working code thanks a lot @tim williams for this, it works but there is a 3 second pause after i press the ok button before the userform closes, any one got any ideas as to why?

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()
    If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Select a member of staff", , "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If CheckBox1.Value = False And CheckBox2.Value = False And CheckBox3.Value = False And CheckBox4.Value = False And CheckBox5.Value = False Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        Dim EmployeeName As String, f As range, tbl As ListObject, Counter As Integer, LastRow As Long, listcolumns As range
        EmployeeName = ComboBox1.Value
        With Sheets("Timetable").ListObjects("TblTimetable")
            LastRow = .range.Rows.Count
            For Counter = LastRow To 1 Step -1
            Set f = .DataBodyRange.Cells(Counter, .listcolumns("Name and Surname").Index)
            If f = EmployeeName Then
                With f.EntireRow
                    .Cells(5).Value = TextBox1.Value
                    .Cells(6).Value = TextBox2.Value
                    .Cells(7).Value = TextBox3.Value
                    .Cells(8).Value = TextBox4.Value
                    .Cells(9).Value = TextBox5.Value
                End With
            End If
            Next Counter
        End With
    End If
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Been some time, but I believe the issue is that you are updating LastRow inside a For loop that is using it as the Endpoint. I do not think VBA supports this, but not 100%. I think you could just update counter instead.

Comment: hey please check my update i think i did what you said, i am not getting anymore errors but it isnt working

Comment: I see LastRow, LastRow1 and LastRow2 -- are these all  correct? where is Lastrow defined? You may also want to dim variables for row numbers as `Long` there can be more rows in Excel than `Integer` can handle

Comment: yeh my code is a mess im trying to combine 2 working pieces of code i made to do something different and its just not working as planned lol.  i doubt i will have more than 50 rows but i will change to long anyway

Comment: ive updated, i think it makes a bit more sense now but still not working, no errors though

Comment: You can add some debug.print statements to figure out where that 3 seconds is going.  If you expect only a single match in your dataset then you can add `Exit For` after you're done updating the found row.

Comment: if i add the exit for after the if f = employeename statement or after the with f.entire row statement it does indeed remove the pause but the values are not inserted, if i move it 1 step down to after it has inserted the values before the end with my values are inserted but the pause is back :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an outline of an approach you can use:

```
    Dim EmployeeName As String, f As Range, tbl As ListObject

    EmployeeName = "Joe Brown"

    Set tbl = Sheets("Timetable").ListObjects("TblTimetable")

    'find the row
    Set f = tbl.ListColumns("Name and Surname").DataBodyRange.Find( _
                                    what:=EmployeeName, lookat:=xlWhole)

    'if found a row, update it
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        With f.EntireRow
            .Cells(4).Value = "Value_1"
            .Cells(5).Value = "Value_2"
            'etc etc
        End With
    End If
```

Comment: hey tim thanks for this, it doesnt work but i didnt get any errors, i edited my original one to be very similar to yours and it works but there is a weird 3 second pause after i press ok before the userform closes, any ideas? i updated my question with the new code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @tim williams for helping me get this functional

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()
    If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Select a member of staff", , "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If CheckBox1.Value = False And CheckBox2.Value = False And CheckBox3.Value = False And CheckBox4.Value = False And CheckBox5.Value = False Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        Dim EmployeeName As String, f As range, tbl As ListObject, Counter As Integer, LastRow As Long, listcolumns As range
        EmployeeName = ComboBox1.Value
        With Sheets("Timetable").ListObjects("TblTimetable")
            LastRow = .range.Rows.Count
            For Counter = LastRow To 1 Step -1
            Set f = .DataBodyRange.Cells(Counter, .listcolumns("Name and Surname").Index)
            If f = EmployeeName Then
                With f.EntireRow
                    .Cells(5).Value = TextBox1.Value
                    .Cells(6).Value = TextBox2.Value
                    .Cells(7).Value = TextBox3.Value
                    .Cells(8).Value = TextBox4.Value
                    .Cells(9).Value = TextBox5.Value
                End With
            End If
            Next Counter
        End With
    End If
    Unload Me
End Sub
```