# Using COUNTIF and SUMIF instead of a loop

Tags: excel, vba

i have working code below but when i press ok there is a 3 second pause before my userform closes. the thing is there will only ever be one result in my table that matches so i dont think i need to actually do it this way and there are more efficient ways. all i need to do is find the row that matches the name then fill the 5 columns of that row with values. is this something suited to COUNTIF and SUMIF? i tried to give it a go but i couldnt get it to stop throwing errors at me which has me questioning if i am doing the right thing.

Here is the updated code. Everything is working as intended but still getting that dam pause, it's really not a big deal i just would like to understand why because i love to learn. I do think a different method that looks for a single match would be better.

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()

    If Me.ComboBox1.Value = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Please Select a member of staff", , "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If


    With TimetableUserForm
        .Hide
        If CheckBox1.Value = False And CheckBox2.Value = False And CheckBox3.Value = False And CheckBox4.Value = False And CheckBox5.Value = False Then
            MsgBox "Error", , "Error"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Dim EmployeeName As String, f As range, tbl As ListObject, Counter As Integer, LastRow As Long, listcolumns As range
            EmployeeName = ComboBox1.Value
            With Sheets("Timetable").ListObjects("TblTimetable")
                LastRow = .range.Rows.Count
                For Counter = LastRow To 1 Step -1
                Set f = .DataBodyRange.Cells(Counter, .listcolumns("Name and Surname").Index)
                If f = EmployeeName Then
                    If TextBox1.Value = vbNullString And TextBox2.Value = vbNullString And TextBox3.Value = vbNullString And TextBox4.Value = vbNullString And TextBox5.Value = vbNullString Then
                        With f.EntireRow
                            .Cells(5).Value = CheckBox1.Value
                            .Cells(6).Value = CheckBox2.Value
                            .Cells(7).Value = CheckBox3.Value
                            .Cells(8).Value = CheckBox4.Value
                            .Cells(9).Value = CheckBox5.Value
                        End With
                    Else
                        With f.EntireRow
                            .Cells(5).Value = TextBox1.Value
                            .Cells(6).Value = TextBox2.Value
                            .Cells(7).Value = TextBox3.Value
                            .Cells(8).Value = TextBox4.Value
                            .Cells(9).Value = TextBox5.Value
                        End With
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
                Next Counter
            End With
        End If
    End With
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Here is the macro that opens up the userform

```
Private Sub Rectangle_16_Click()
If Sheets("Settings").range("Protected") = 1 Then
            'do nothing
            Else
TimetableUserForm.Show
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In your previous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58035536/finding-a-row-in-a-table-and-inserting-values-from-userform you already got suggestions for the "more efficient way" - using `Find()` is one alternative, or you can use `Match()`.  To find out where the 3 seconds is being taken, you can use `Timer` and Debug.Print or MsgBox http://excelteacher.com/vba/code/simple-vba-code-timing-excel-macros/

Comment: hey, find didnt work in the code you posted i dont know what, i figured since we got the code working using this current method in that sheet i should close that question and start a new one looking for better methods. i tried to use debug.print with the immediate window but ive never used it before and i had no clue what i was doing lol, i will check out that link you posted now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

place an `Exit For` right after filling cells

moreover here are some more suggestions:

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()

    With Me ' reference the Userform
        .Hide ' hide the userform

        If .ComboBox1.Value = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "Please Select a member of staff", , "Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If .CheckBox1 Or .CheckBox2 Or .CheckBox3 Or .CheckBox4 Or .CheckBox5 Then
            Dim EmployeeName As String, f As Range, tbl As ListObject, Counter As Integer, LastRow As Long, listcolumns As Range
            EmployeeName = .ComboBox1.Value
            With Sheets("Timetable").ListObjects("TblTimetable")
                LastRow = .Range.Rows.Count
                For Counter = LastRow To 1 Step -1
                    Set f = .DataBodyRange.Cells(Counter, .listcolumns("Name and Surname").Index)
                    If f = EmployeeName Then
                        With f.EntireRow
                            .Cells(5).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
                            .Cells(6).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
                            .Cells(7).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
                            .Cells(8).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
                            .Cells(9).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
                        End With
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End With
        End If

    End With

'    Unload Me ' <-- move Unload command in the sub that has shown the userform
End Sub
```

As to the proper place for `Unload` command, here's your `Rectangle_16_Click()` revision:

```
Private Sub Rectangle_16_Click()
    If Sheets("Settings").range("Protected") = 1 Then
            'do nothing
    Else
        With New TimetableUserForm ' instantiate a new instance of your Userform class and reference 
            .Show ' show it
        End With ' this will set the reference object to Nothing      
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great! how do i move unload me to the sub that fires off the userform im not sure where to place it? what was the reasoning for changing "" to vbNullString? i know your way is more complete. i promise i added exit for exactly there and it was just causing non of my values to be inserted but you have done it and it works perfectly what is the reason?

ok so performance it closes right away and my values are sent but the windows hourglass shows for a couple of seconds after i press ok, normal?

Comment: also whats the reason to use me.textbox and not just text box?

Comment: 1) update the question showing the code the fires the userform 2) using vbNullString in lieu of “” optimizes the performance, If I recall it right using “” force the compiler to create an empty string variable 3) update the question showing your not working code with the exit for 4) as for the windows hour glass I guess your sheet is doing some calculations 5) if answer solved your question you may consider marking it as accepted

Comment: updated thanks for that, good to know that about vbnullstring im going to change every instance of "" in my sheet

Comment: the pause is no longer noticeable as i have moved the button to a different sheet, it now works perfectly, i just want to understand what you are saying about the unload me command now as its in the wrong place according to you.

Comment: see edited answer for proper `Unload` command place: actually `Unload` isn't necessary anymore since the Userform object is set to Nothing by means of its instantiation in a `With...End With` block. Finaly, if my answer solved your question, you may want to accept it. Thank you

Comment: hey i am now getting an error "must close or hide topmost modal form first. also what does this do "If .CheckBox1 Or .CheckBox2 Or .CheckBox3 Or .CheckBox4 Or .CheckBox5 Then"